# Why can't i append to manager.list()?

Tags: python, list, multiprocessing

The output should be: `[[], ['new element'], []]` but is `[[], [], []]` just blank. Why?

```
from multiprocessing import Manager

if __name__ == '__main__':# Create a Manager object
    manager = Manager()

    # Create a shared list of lists
    shared_list = manager.list([[], [], []])

    # Append an element to the second index
    element = "New Element"
    shared_list[1].append(element)

    # Print the updated shared list
    print(shared_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you aren't appending to the `manager.list` *anywhere*. You are retrieving a value, which copies a new object into your current process. That value is a list, when you then append to. But the `manager.list` has no way of knowing that. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects):

> If standard (non-proxy) `list` or `dict` objects are contained in a
> referent, modifications to those mutable values will not be propagated
> through the manager because the proxy has no way of knowing when the
> values contained within are modified. However, storing a value in a
> container proxy (which triggers a `__setitem__` on the proxy object)
> does propagate through the manager and so to effectively modify such
> an item, one could re-assign the modified value to the container proxy

So you could do:

```
inner = shared_list[1]
inner.append(element)
shared_list[1] = inner
```